# HTAccess Redirect To Remove File

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, redirect, url-rewriting

My side resides in

```
www.domain.com/Folder/Front.php
```

So *inside* of Folder I have a .htaccess file that just has one line reading:

```
DirectoryIndex Front.php
```

So typing in `www.domain.com/Folder` is the same thing as `www.domain.com/Folder/Front.php`. However I want to *redirect* `www.domain.com/Folder/Front.php` **TO** `www.domain.com/Folder`. I know I have to have something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
```

But I don't know what the Cond or Rule would be. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Put a 301 redirect in the header of your php file if the uri includes the name of the file.

Comment: I guess I'll write it out for you ;) give me a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in a .htaccess at root level and it will redirect any request to AnyFolder/Front.php to AnyFolder/

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\/Front.php$ $1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: i really don't understand why this won't work. Your code looks perfectly fine but when I type in `www.domain.com/Folder/Front.php` it just stays there rather than go to `www.domain.com/Folder`

Comment: Could you clear your cache, or open a private browsing window and try? The updates to the .htaccess may not be being picked up. I sometimes get that on Chrome whilst developing on my local server.

Comment: Also, just to clarify that this should go in a htaccess at the document root level of your server, not inside the Folder directory.

Comment: oh nvm it was the placement of the file that was the problem. But now it redirects to `www.domain.com/disks/vhosts/folder/Folder` but I want it to just go to `www.domain.com/Folder`

Comment: Is the line `RewriteBase /` present in the .htaccess file? That should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a 301 redirect at the top of Front.php which sees if the URI includes `Front.php`.  If it does, it will redirect the user to the root folder.  A 301 redirect will also ensure that any robots will direct to the base directory as well.

**Place at the top of your Front.php file**

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'Front.php' === FALSE):

   header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
   header("Location: http://www.domain.com/Folder/");

else:

   // Rest of page goes here

endif;
```

Comment: ok, out of curiosity why don't you do this in the htaccess file? Any particular reason?

Comment: I prefer to handle individual file redirects on the files themselves to keep a little bit of order. Well, actually, I typically use an MVC setup (CodeIgniter), where it's not as much of an issue.  Also, I don't know a ton of htaccess methods.

Comment: I strongly disagree that this method "keeps order". If anything it will only create chaos if you create several redirects across your site in individual files. How do you manage them? Keeping them contained in a single .htaccess at root level is easily the best and most manageable method.

Comment: @amustill - Again, as I mentioned in my post, I don't typically use this method.  I usually have controllers which handle redirects. If he has one folder in which he want's a redirect, this method would be absolutely fine.  If, however, a redirect is required because a page no longer exists, I would certainly go htaccess.  In my case, I have much more experience working with php than htaccess files, so I gave the answer that I knew how to explain.